# Application is not deployed to jenkins npm error

Tags: node.js, jenkins

Application is not deployed to jenkins. error in logs:
[image]

[image]

the solution is possible in the "npm cache clear --force", but where to enter it, should the developer do it? or I, devops, in jenkins?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include all code and errors as text and not as images.  How are you deploying your app with Jenkins?

Comment: deploy with buildTool = "npm" in jenkins pipline.

Comment: can i add "npm cache clear --force" to jenkins? if yes, where to put it?